# OpenCascade BRepBuilderAPI_GTransform with fillets always throws errors

Tags: c++, geometry, opencascade

When using an OpenCascade **BRepBuilderAPI_GTransform** with **fillets** seem always to throw a construction error (*StdFail_NotDone*), while a non-G-Transform (as BRepBuilderAPI_Transform) works (however does not for example allow for non-uniform axis scaling). What is it about the GTransform that is an issue here, and is there some way that it can be overcome?

Minimal error example below with scaling and fillet of a unit triangle.

```
// Unit triangle
BRepBuilderAPI_MakePolygon polyMaker;
polyMaker.Add(BRepBuilderAPI_MakeVertex(gp_XYZ(0, 0, 0)));
polyMaker.Add(BRepBuilderAPI_MakeVertex(gp_XYZ(1, 0, 0)));
polyMaker.Add(BRepBuilderAPI_MakeVertex(gp_XYZ(0, 1, 0)));
polyMaker.Close();
TopoDS_Shape face = BRepBuilderAPI_MakeFace(polyMaker.Wire());

// Apply unit transformation
gp_GTrsf gtrsf;
face = BRepBuilderAPI_GTransform(face, gtrsf, true);

// Fillet on vertex 1
TopTools_IndexedMapOfShape vmap;
TopExp::MapShapes(face, TopAbs_VERTEX, vmap);
BRepFilletAPI_MakeFillet2d filletMaker(TopoDS::Face(face));
filletMaker.AddFillet(TopoDS::Vertex(vmap(1)), 0.1);
TopoDS_Shape fillet = filletMaker.Shape();

// ERROR: terminate called after throwing an instance of 'StdFail_NotDone'
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a solution, but I can add that the output of gp_Trsf based transformations are "safer" because they preserve the type of geometry (circle curve is still a circle etc)

This is not true of gp_GTrsf, e.g. a circle can become an ellipse (see https://unlimited3d.wordpress.com/2021/03/28/transformations-in-occt/ ). When I've experimented with gp_GTrsf it seems like the output edges are commonly a bspline-curve. Perhaps that could be why the fillets subsequently fail.